# Scheduling Casting or automatic default casting device on Chromecast

Tags: chromecast

We have a TV in our office that has Chromecast. We are using this TV to cast our metrics in a dashboard (a few separate charts on different webpages). We use the same TV for some internal meetings (e.g., standups). I want the TV to be casting our dashboard whenever the secondary casting device stops casting so we don't have to do it manually. What is my best option to do this? If it helps, our meetings are at specific times so I can potentially schedule casting of the dashboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think this is possible as this was asked in this [thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromecast/E1PdJiEfsj4):

> No; .., I am afraid.  Chromecast is just a pipe, with no user
>   interface or ability to do such things.